# How can i add a triangle in the background in a WPF Form?

Tags: wpf, xaml

[image: The green triangle that i am trying to create]

I am trying to create a green triangular background in the WPF form. And trying to add the login panel in front of it, so part of it is hidden. How can i go about doing it? I am trying to do everything using XAML, and not using controls at all.

I tried adding custom shapes, something called Path Geometry, but i have no idea how to go about it. Thank you for helping in advance!!!

Comment: Show the code you have (XAML), a screenshot of the result and a drawing of the required result. Then it will be possible to help you more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Grid` and place the controls in the same cell to stack them. The control you want at the bottom has to come first.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="600"
        Height="400"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="Primary">#42553b</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryBrush"
                         Color="{StaticResource Primary}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <!-- triangle comes first -->

        <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
            <Polygon Fill="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}"
                     Points="100,0 0,100, 100,100"
                     StrokeThickness="0" />
        </Viewbox>

        <!-- content above the triangle -->

        <Grid Margin="80">
            <Rectangle Fill="White"
                       RadiusX="10"
                       RadiusY="10"
                       Stroke="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}"
                       StrokeThickness="1" />
            <Grid Width="400"
                  Height="200">
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Content="Whatever you want goes here" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]